# Parsing string containing ascii codes to float

Tags: python, floating-point, visa, gpib

I'm using [pyvisa](http://pyvisa.sourceforge.net/) to control a Signal recovery sr7225 lockin amplifier. Almost everything works as expected. There is only one problem, when the queried value is exactly zero and one queries in the floating point mode the following is returned

```
>>>import visa
>>>lockin = visa.instrument('GPIB::08')
>>>lockin.ask('X.') # Query X value in floating point mode
0.0E+00\x00
```

An ascii value is appended to the response string. I guess the appended ascii value of `\x00` is a bug, but it means that I cannot use `float()` to convert the string response to float. How would you handle this?

Comment: It's a null byte, a string terminator in C.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm just wondering why it's only sent if the value is exactly zero and not otherwise.

Comment: Probably a bug, as you say; just wanted to explain where it may have come from. It has meaning in C, and may thus have been missed as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply

`float(x.strip('\x00'))` ?